# Put multiple regular expression patterns into one pattern as attribute in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expressions which validate if a password contains at least one uppercase, at least one lowercase, and at least one digit.

```
Regex rxLowercase = new Regex( @"\p{Ll}" ); // Unicode: All lowercase letters
Regex rxUppercase = new Regex( @"\p{Lu}" ); // Unicode: All uppercase letters
Regex rxDigits = new Regex( @"\p{Nd}" ); // Unicode: All decimal digits
```

I want to put an attribute to a specific property like

```
[RegularExpression( /* something here which combines above expressions */ )]
[StringLength( 1024, MinimumLength = 8 )]
public string NewPassword
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them using three different look aheads like this:

```
(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Nd})
```

Comment: @DavidArno I am replying to someone who had put a comment giving me a suggestion. I should remove my reply now as he had removed his comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since your regex's are all initialised from strings, just make the constructor for the RegularExpression attribute accept an array of strings.

I'd suggest changing NewPassword to a method (you should never implement passwords such that you can get at the value, hash them and compare the hashes to find out if passwords match).

To then get at the attribute from within the methods, use something like:

```
var attribute = (RegularExpression)typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("NewPassword")
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RegularExpression), false).First();
```

Comment: How to combines all ? with `.` symbol ?

Comment: Why make life complicated? You could construct a single - complex and difficult to read - regex that can test all three conditions, but the code will be simpler and easier to understand if you test each regex in turn.

Comment: @SnakeEyes, I've updated the answer to address that.